# OS Architecture: Kernel and Standard Library interoperability

Tags: c, architecture, linux-kernel, kernel, osdev

As always I thank you for your time and effort in assisting me on my journey :)

So being a nerd I have started pulling back the layers of how the OS works. Where I have a question is around the kernel and the standard libraries, such as glibc for Linux, which acts as a function wrapper.

Why does the OS need a standard library which is written in C? OR asked another way Could you write a standard library for the Linux kernel in another language other than C?

I assume that and that the language of the STD library may be dependent on the language chosen for the Kernel. So in our example of Linux, which is written in C, the wrapper STD library also needed to be C.

I understand why the kernel needs the STD library in general so that isn't really what I am trying to get at JIC I wasn't clear.

Thanks Again!

Comment: Also please include reference material if possible.

Comment: Part of the standard library is OS specific, used for operations like memory allocation / freeing, I/O operations, ..., the rest of it is fairly generic, internally calling OS specific functions if needed. . The library could be written in just about any compiled or assembled language as long as it is C / C++ compatible.

Answer (score 3):

Let's dive in more details about OS - userspace communication. Do you know how it goes? Basically each platform uses its own approach to make a so called syscall -> control transfer from userspace to kernelspace.
For example x86 uses `int` instruction, x86-64 uses `syscall` instruction, arm uses `swi` and so on. Also each platform has its own understanding of how parameters and syscall number should be established before syscall instruction is called. Let's focus on x86-64:
For example for calling execve (syscall number 0x3b) this code is enough. You can try it.

```
section .text
    global _start
_start:                
    mov rax, 0x3b             
    mov rdi, cmd             
    mov rsi, 0
    mov rdx, 0
    syscall

section .data
    cmd: db '/bin/sh'
.end:
```

Now let's understand what is `execve` libc function. Basically if you will dive into libc code, you will see that it is wrapper which leads to syscall function (see syscall.S for your arch in libc). This syscall.S looks pretty same with our example above:

```
    .text
ENTRY (syscall)
    movq %rdi, %rax     /* Syscall number -> rax.  */
    movq %rsi, %rdi     /* shift arg1 - arg5.  */
    movq %rdx, %rsi
    movq %rcx, %rdx
    movq %r8, %r10
    movq %r9, %r8
    movq 8(%rsp),%r9    /* arg6 is on the stack.  */
    syscall         /* Do the system call.  */
```

So basically, as **user4098326** and **rcgldr** have mentioned - the interconnection between uspace and kernel is assembly code, and all things above it - just wrappers. So as i understand all this wrappers could be written **not only in C**.

Answer (score -1):

General kernel driver works through file operations, like open, close, read, & write.

Again, as kernel is also written completely in C.

So due to these 2 reasons
, I think, we can not write lower level library calls in other language.

Comment: Parts of the kernel and the standard library are written in assembly. These parts usually use low-level features that are not in C.

Comment: Kernel is mostly in C, not completely. But it is also not in assembly completely. At last C code loaded as assembly code. Some of code in kernel is assembly which is specific to machine and provided my manufacturer itself. This assembly code gets linked with final kernel image.